# DAX don't support comparing values of type integer with values type of text

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is DAX formula in Power BI that should create new measure in a table but I faced error saying

> DAX don't support comparing values of type integer with values type of text...

This formula is designed to calculated Sum of the Offers for the previous year vs selected one.  `Offer[Year]` is decimal field used in the formula is decimal type:

```
Offer Amount Prev Year = IF(HASONEVALUE(Offer[Year]), CALCULATE(SUM(Offer[Offer Amount]), Offer[Year] = FORMAT(VALUES(Offer[Year]) - 1, BLANK())))
```

How to solve the error from above?

Comment: Can you provide any sample data and example(s) of what your desired outcome is/are? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies at the `FORMAT` function.

`Offer[Year]` is an integer while `FORMAT(VALUES(Offer[Year]) - 1, BLANK())` is text, hence DAX don't support comparing the two values.

If you remove the `FORMAT` function then it should be working.

```
Offer Amount Prev Year = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(Offer[Year]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Offer[Offer Amount]),
        Offer[Year] = VALUES(Offer[Year]) - 1
    )
)
```